# Annotating with Avg works in sqlite but not postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, django-orm

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    RATING_CHOICES = (
        ('1', 'One Star - I can\'t recommend it'),
        ('2', 'Two Star - It was okay'),
        ('3', 'Three Star - I liked it'),
        ('4', 'Four Star - I liked it!'),
        ('5', 'Five Star - I loved it! New favorite!'),
        )
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=RATING_CHOICES, blank=False)
    media_object = models.ForeignKey(MediaObject)
    ...
```

A given `MediaObject` may have many `Reviews`, as you can see. I would like to get a queryset of all `MediaObjects` sorted by the average `rating` of each object's `Reviews`.

The following lookup works perfectly when using SQLite:

```
MediaObject.objects.all().annotate(ravg=Avg('review__rating')).order_by('-ravg')
```

However, on postgresql, that lookup returns the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: function avg(character varying) does not exist
```

I understand the error but do not understand how I can fix/work around it. How can I cast `rating` to a number in this case before trying to `Avg` it using the Django ORM?

---

Edit: I understand that the ideal solution would be to store these values in an `IntegerField` rather than a `CharField` in the first place. This is an inherited project, however, and at the moment that sort of alteration is beyond the scope of my authority. [This blog post](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/nov/02/handle-choices-right-way/) outlines what I believe to be the "proper" solution to this question - changing the way the data is stored to begin with. I wish I could just do this, and if this were my personal project that's how I'd handle it.

Assume for a moment that this field must necessarily be a `CharField` - is it possible to cast the value stored in `Review.rating` to an integer before calling `Avg` using the ORM, or would this need to be done through [raw SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)?

Comment: `rating = models.CharField` suggests that your `rating` column is a string when it should be an integer, why is your rating an string?. You should also stop developing on SQLite if you're deploying on PostgreSQL.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the issue. To my knowledge you must use a `CharField` when using the `choices` argument (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#choices). If it is possible to store this value initially as an integer, I would be happy doing that as well. Can you use the `choices` argument with an `IntegerField`? If not, how can I convert / cast to an integer before averaging? And regardless of the development environment, I want to understand how this works under both DB architectures.

Comment: Don't know any Django but are you sure that `choices` is only valid with `CharField`?